# oauth-4-laravel - Just need a simple Application Only Auth and search/tweets.json

Tags: laravel, twitter, laravel-4, oauth

I am using https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel#basic-usage library for Laravel 4

The example they provide is how to login with Twitter. I DO NOT NEED THAT.

All I am trying to do is send a GET request to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json with my query. THAT IS ALL!!

However, it keeps complaining that I need to Authenticate my application. No Internet forum has been left unturned searching for a tutorial. NOTHING. Virtually every post is how to login with twitter.

I have read this: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only but failing to understand how to get Bearer Token via Oauth-4-Laravel library. Anyone has experience with this specific library to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that my answer isn't referring to the library you're using, but I can't comment on things yet.

You can use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) to do this with Guzzle's OauthPlugin. It should be fairly easy.

Laracasts did an [example](https://github.com/laracasts/HTTP-Requests-Refactoring-Lesson/tree/master/app/Acme/Twitter) connection to Twitter. I believe that uses Guzzle 3 or 4.

The most recent Guzzle is Guzzle 6. I had a bit of trouble integrating that with Laravel 5. But have a look at how I did it, it may be of help to you. https://github.com/votemike/shorttwittername/tree/master/app/Twitter